# MS Access SQL Not Working as desired

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query which goes like this.

`SELECT *
FROM <database1>
WHERE (Condition1) AND (Condition2 or Condition3)`

My desired result should be rows satisfying condition1 **and** rows satisfying either condition 2 or condition3.

But the SQL is giving me rows that are just satisfying condition1. It seems that the 'OR' operator between the condition2 and condition3 is doing something.

Expert opinion sought. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: can you provide sample data as well as the actual query?  there might be some incorrect syntax causing the issue

Comment: are you sure the bolded "AND" shouldn't be an OR?  meaning you want anything that's an apple OR anything that's a veggie or a meat  Or do you really want everything thats an apple and a veggie or a meat which should yield no results.

Comment: See the sample sql. its exactly the same but for the real names.. `SELECT *
FROM <Database>
WHERE ( 
([Title] Like '*Term1*' OR [Title] = '' OR [Title] = '' OR [Title] = '' OR [Title] = '' OR [Title] = '' OR [Title] = '' OR [Title] = '' OR [Title] = '' OR [Title] = '')
and
(
([Title] LIKE '*Term1*' OR '*Term3*' OR '*Indonesia*' or [Country] IN ('*India*','*Indonesia*'))
)
)`

Comment: Hi Qbert, Think in this way... The condition2 and condition3 are a subset of condition1. Lets say, 10 lines satisfy condition1, then it should check for how many lines in those 10 lines satisfy condition2 or condition3. Please let me know if my logic is flawed in the first place. Thanks for your reply..

Comment: @user1087661: You have a `[Title] = ''` that is repeating numerous times. Why? Please, add the query you have by editing the question, not in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your comment you put:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <Database> 
WHERE 
    (
        (   [Title] Like '*Term1*' 
         OR [Title] = '' 
         OR [Title] = '' 
         OR [Title] = '' 
         OR [Title] = '' 
         OR [Title] = '' 
         OR [Title] = '' 
         OR [Title] = '' 
         OR [Title] = '' 
         OR [Title] = ''
        ) 
    and 
        (
            (   [Title] LIKE '*Term1*' 
             OR '*Term3*' 
             OR '*Indonesia*' 
             or [Country] IN ('*India*','*Indonesia*')
            )
        )
    )
```

Laid out like this you can see the structure a bit easier.

The biggest thing that is probably throwing you is the mix of `LIKE`, `OR` and `IN` operators in the second part.

`LIKE` is the only operator that can deal with wildcards, `OR` and `IN` can't.

You'd probably meant something like:

```
            (   [Title] LIKE '*Term1*' 
             OR [Title] LIKE '*Term3*' 
             OR [Title] LIKE '*Indonesia*' 
             OR [Country] LIKE '*India*'
             OR [Country] LIKE '*Indonesia*'
            )
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but, try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM <database1> WHERE ((Condition1) AND (Condition2 or Condition3))
```

hope this will be solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are not used in `IN`:

```
[Country] IN ('*India*','*Indonesia*')
```

doesn't mean what you think it means